# My Finder file detail headers looks weird

Tags: finder

My Finder's file details header looks weird.

[image]

It looks translucent and not clickable :(
I used many command-line tools on this `Temp` folder, so I could be happen from accidental deletion of some system file. But I can't figure out what actually happen in there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used *View » Arrange By* or a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> shortcut. It's new in Lion. Remove it by selecting *View » Arrange By » None* (or pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>).

Hold down <kbd>⌥</kbd> while opening the *View* menu to get the older *Sort By…* menu, or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> instead.